# Spelling of 5,400

Tags: numbers

How can I spell to the number 5.400 ? Five thousand and four  hundred or without  using " and"

Comment: Either way.  Usually without "and".  "Five thousand, four hundred and forty-two" would be more normal than without the "and", however.

Comment: I've closed this as a duplicate of your previous question because I can't nominate more than one, and two relevant questions appear in comments on that previous post. Please don't keep repeating similar questions. Apply the rules which already appear in answers on the site: if you can't do that, or there is some ambiguity, make sure you include in your question what is not clear.

Answer (score 3):

> Five thousand four hundred

would be correct and signify the number 5400.

Five thousand and four hundred could potentially mean 5000 and 400.

> E.g. There are two groups of people with about five thousand and four
>   hundred in each group.  E.g   There is one group with about
>   five thousand four hundred people in it.

Comment: With an optional comma. 'Five thousand, four hundred and fifty-seven,' which also shows where and is usual, in UK at least, and reminds you of the hyphen, too.